# How to install and upgrade other software in spite of libreoffice unmet dependency errors?

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, libreoffice, root

**TLDR: When I try to run `apt-get install` or `apt-get upgrade`, the desired action does not occur, and I get err message about libreoffice unmet dependencies.**

Lately, when I try to install a program via command line by typing `sudo apt-get install` etc., the program does NOT install, and I get an error message about libreoffice:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libreoffice-style-breeze : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial2) but 1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial1 is to be installed
 libreoffice-style-galaxy : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial2) but 1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I get the same response when I try to run `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

When I then run `sudo apt-get -f install`, it tells me:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-71 linux-headers-4.4.0-71-generic linux-image-4.4.0-71-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-71-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libreoffice-common
Suggested packages:
  libreoffice-style-hicontrast libreoffice-style-human libreoffice-style-oxygen
  libreoffice-style-sifr libreoffice-style-tango
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libreoffice-common
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 55 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/22.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 1,024 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

I tell the terminal `Y`. It replies:

```
(Reading database ... 273520 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libreoffice-common_1%3a5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-common (1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial2) over (1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial2_all.deb (--unpack):
 unable to open '/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/template/wizard/bitmap/euro_3.bmp.dpkg-new': Operation not permitted
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

When I then try to install other programs, I get this error:

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

Therefore, I run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and get this response:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-style-galaxy:
 libreoffice-style-galaxy depends on libreoffice-common (= 1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial2); however:
  Version of libreoffice-common on system is 1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial1.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-style-galaxy (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up shared-mime-info (1.5-2ubuntu0.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-style-breeze:
 libreoffice-style-breeze depends on libreoffice-style-galaxy; however:
  Package libreoffice-style-galaxy is not configured yet.
 libreoffice-style-breeze depends on libreoffice-common (= 1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial2); however:
  Version of libreoffice-common on system is 1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial1.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-style-breeze (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libreoffice-style-galaxy
 libreoffice-style-breeze
```

I still can't successfully run `apt-get install` or `apt-get upgrade`, so I then try to remove libreoffice entirely via `sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice*` and get a long reply ending in the following...

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-uno : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I again try `sudo apt-get -f install` and get the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-71 linux-headers-4.4.0-71-generic linux-image-4.4.0-71-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-71-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libreoffice-common
Suggested packages:
  libreoffice-style-hicontrast libreoffice-style-human libreoffice-style-oxygen
  libreoffice-style-sifr libreoffice-style-tango
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libreoffice-common
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 55 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/22.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 1,024 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 273520 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libreoffice-common_1%3a5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-common (1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial2) over (1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial2_all.deb (--unpack):
 unable to open '/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/gallery/htmlexpo/grenav.gif.dpkg-new': Operation not permitted
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I've looked through similar questions online but seem just to be going in circles. How can I fix the problem so that I can install other programs?

Comment: »» When I try to run apt-get install «« : Before doing the install or upgrade command, please do `sudo apt-get update` , in order to refresh the package list.

Comment: Could you please run `sudo apt-get remove -f libreoffice\*` and [edit] your question to include the output? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this to work. Looks like my Sophos AV was preventing the update.

```
 sudo /opt/sophos-av/bin/savdctl disable
 sudo apt-get install -f
 sudo apt-get upgrade
 sudo /opt/sophos-av/bin/savdctl enable
```

Comment: Thank you! After trying a bunch of work-arounds to be able to install and upgrade software (in spite of the seemingly insoluble libreoffice unmet dependency errors), I finally just reinstalled Ubuntu. However, I *did* have SophosAV, as well, so that could be what the problem was.

Comment: In case it's helpful to anyone with a similar issue (i.e., not being able to use apt-get install or apt-get upgrade because an existing program has an unmet dependency error), here is the work-around that I used for a while: I used "aptitude install", "aptitude update", and "aptitude upgrade" instead of "apt-get install", etc., for a while. Not sure if that is even advisable, but it at least allowed me to install new software so that was helpful.